# Inject some string to a specific part of string in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

How to insert some string to a specific part of another string. What i am trying to achieve is i have an html string like this in my variable say `string stringContent;`

```
 <html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <meta name="Viewport" content="width=320; user-scaleable=no; 
 initial-scale=1.0">
 <style type="text/css"> 
 body {
       background: black;
       color: #80c0c0; 
 } 
 </style>
 <script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="callNative();">Call to Native 
Code!</button>

<br><br>
</body></html>
```

I need to add below string content inside `<script> <script/>` tag

```
    function callNative()
{
    window.external.notify("Uulalaa!");
}
    function addToBody(text)
{
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<br>" + text;
}
```

How i can achieve this in C#.

Comment: look into stringbuilders.

Comment: Consider using RazorEngine.

Comment: [MSDN StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your content is stored in the string `content`, you can start by finding the script tag with:

```
int scriptpos = content.IndexOf("<script");
```

Then to get past the end of the script tag:

```
scriptpos = content.IndexOf(">", scriptpos) + 1;
```

And finally to insert your new content:

```
content = content.Insert(scriptpos, newContent);
```

This at least allows for potential attributes in the script tag.

Comment: you should not forget that strings are immutable in C# and `content.Insert` will not modify the content, so you have to re-assign it by new value.

Comment: All answers are acceptable.. But i am marking this one only because of the up votes it gain.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `htmlString.Replace(what, with)`

```
var htmlString = "you html bla bla where's the script tag? oooups here it is!!!<script></script>";

var yourScript = "alert('HA-HA-HA!!!')";

htmlString = htmlString.Replace("<script>", "<script>" + yourScript);
```

Note that this will insert `yourScript` inside all `<script>` elements.

Comment: Which other answer suggested using the `Replace` method?!

Comment: Sry it was a mistake.. I just remove the comment, Thanks for the effort. I will give you +1 for your ans

Comment: +1, copypasting my example text is nothing bad, the code itself is different, so the answer is absolutely Ok.

Comment: @ArturUdod : Sry for the trouble, I didn't find the change part. here is my apologies. I am so sorry to make such a comment.

Comment: @StezPet, absolutely no offence, I just wanted to say I don't mind using parts of my answer, since we're having a solution-oriented discussion here, I beleive you should not apologise.

Answer (score 2):

```
var htmlString = @"<script>$var1</script> <script>$var2</script>"
                 .Replace("$var1", "alert('var1')")
                 .Replace("$var2", "alert('var2')");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlString = "you html bla bla where's the script tag? oooups here it is!!!<script></script>";

var yourScript = "alert('HA-HA-HA!!!')";

htmlString = htmlString.Insert(html.IndexOf("<script>") + "<script>".Length + 1, yourScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can read the html file into string by using File.ReadAllText method. Here For example, i have used sample html string. After that, by some string operations you can add tags under script like follows.

```
string text = "<test> 10 </test>";
string htmlString = 
    @" <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                <tag1> 5 </tag1>
            </script>
        </head>
      </html>";

int startIndex = htmlString.IndexOf("<script>");
int length = htmlString.IndexOf("</script>") - startIndex;
string scriptTag = htmlString.Substring(startIndex, length) + "</script>";
string expectedScripTag = scriptTag.Replace("<script>", "<script><br>" + text);
htmlString = htmlString.Replace(scriptTag, expectedScripTag);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in another (safer) way, using **HTML Agility Pack** (open source project http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com). It helps you to parse and edit html without you having to worry about malformed tags (`<br/>, <br />, < br / >` etc). It includes operations to make it easy to insert elements, like `AppendChild`.

If you are dealing with HTML, this is the way to go.